# How to add/trigger-exposure-of twiddle-down for Code Signing Identity field in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing

In Xcode, in only one project (that is, all other projects work the way I expect), in the Target Info window, build tab, the Code Signing Identity field-title does **not** have the twiddle to expose the "Any iPhone OS Device" field.

How do I add it or trigger its exposure?

Comment: What's a twiddle? Seriously, I've never heard that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha!  I just had to look a little further.  In the bottom of the info window is a little gear-icon and, under that popup is "Add Build Setting Condition" which, once added, produces a build-setting popup which contains "Any iPhone OS Device."

Whew!

(Hope this is helpful for the next guy...)